# How i can save the changes for my SELECT Replace() inside SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2, and I have a tale named `Sales Data`. I want to replace all the following characters `XholderX` with `,` inside a column named `address`.

I tried to execute the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Replace(Address, 'XholderX', ',') AS P
FROM [SalesDataDemo].[dbo].[Sales Data]
WHERE Address LIKE '%XholderX%'
```

which retrieves all the rows which match the criteria, and shows them inside a column named P. But my question is: how can I save the changes inside the database? So all the `xholderx` will be replaced by `,` inside the `Address` column.

Thanks

Comment: SO cannot possibly have been the last place you looked for this after doing your own research. Google "SQL UPDATE".

Comment: @JacobH so how i can add my sql statement inside an sql update ?

Comment: @johnG  Into `SET` statement  you could place your expression in this case as `Replace`.  if you would like read more about it, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
UPDATE [SalesDataDemo].[dbo].[Sales Data]
SET Address =  Replace(Address, 'XholderX', ',')
WHERE Address LIKE '%XholderX%'
```